# Dealing with absence of coverage

Tags: snakemake, deeptools, workflow-management, errors

In my snakemake workflow, I use deeptools `bamCoverage` (in a `make_bigwig` rule), then `computeMatrix` and `plotProfile` (in different `plot_*_profile` rules) to create coverage profiles for various kinds of small RNAs. It sometimes happens that there are very few reads in a particular category of small RNAs. This results in `bamCoverage` exiting with an error (when I use the `--skipNAs` option, in order to make coverage profiles not take into account empty regions):

```
Error: The generated bedGraphFile was empty. Please adjust
your deepTools settings and check your input files.
```

The fact that `bamCoverage` fails make things a little annoying for me, because the later the failure, the easier to handle things in my workflow: I will need to catch the error and generate a dummy output file in the `make_bigwig` rule, and then handle the special dummy file in the `plot_*_profile` rules.

I would be fine having an empty coverage file: the absence of reads (either in the bam file, or matching selection criteria in `bamCoverage`) is not due to an error.

**Is this just not possible, by the format definition?**

**Did I miss an option to have `bamCoverage` accept making empty files?**

**Would this make `computeMatrix` fail?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll fix the `bamCoverage` issue in the 2.6.0 release (it may already be fixed since I rewrite how bigWig files are made for that release). You can follow my status [on the issue page](https://github.com/fidelram/deepTools/issues/598). In principle you should be able to do this, it's just a deepTools limitation.

This should work fine with `computeMatrix`, though keep in mind that you're just going to get a big block of NA values.

**Update**: This error ends up coming from pyBigWig. I've just found that `bedGraphToBigWig` also can't make a bigWig file with now entries, so I suspect this is sort of undefined behavior. Regardless, I'll alter pyBigWig to produce a file that it can open and use in a meaningful manner.